# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE in Salesforce via API

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to make a batch update to Salesforce as part of a data masking project and am getting the error **INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE** when I try updating fields of a particular custom object via API. 
Our custom object has a few standard fields and a few custom fields. The custom fields are what I'm trying to update but I keep getting denied.

Each field that I'm trying to update is either Long Text Area(32768) or Text(255). There are no lookups, controlling fields, validation rules, nor are there field dependencies. 
I am able to make modifications to other objects (Account for example) via the masking process. I am also able to make modifications to the values through the web UI on the values for this custom object. 
I've tried as members of the API group as well as System Administrator.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I don't have access to the source code of the masking tool, but I do have elevated rights in SF. 
Thanks in advance for your advice.

The exact error: 
*INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE Error message: Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.*

The funny thing is that I'm not trying to update the field "Name". Name seems to be an auto-number field on the object, but I'm not sure why this field would change value on an update to a different column.

Comment: Can you provide full error message? More details can better help to solve your issue

Comment: Updated with error message. Thanks, Last Khajiit.

Comment: The Name field, usually, is standard field of each SF object. You sure, is it writable? Sometimes it can be autonumber type and in such case you have not ability to populate it.

Comment: I do see the auto-number Name field, and it is read-only. Is there anything that would tell me why this field is being updated when i'm only changing the value of a seemingly unrelated field.

Comment: If field is autonumber, that mean - this field autopopulated identifier (like ID). It's not writable (at all), you can only read this field. If you need Name field as a usual writable text field you need to change type of the filed to "Text"

Comment: Right - I see that. But i'm trying to update a field called "Comment" which is Long Text Area and it seems that Salesforce is trying to make an update to "Name". Is there a way to see why SF is trying to update NAME?

Comment: It seam to me, your app generate such request to SF, with passing value for Name field. I'm not sure how to check it if you don't have access to source code of app.. Try to catch requests to SF if it's REST Api

Comment: Thank you for your help this afternoon. I'll see what I can capture.

Comment: LK - on your advice, i changed the field to text from autonumber during the masking process and then flipped it back afterwards. I don't know why the name was set up like this, but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

If some one facing the same issue of not able to update the Name column because it has data type as Name.

There are 2 solutions:

1. If you want to push the name of human then try pushing FirstName and LastName instead. "Name" will get populated automatically.
2. If you want to push the name of a product then try changing the type of Name field to Text. If that doesn't work then you can push the name to either FirstName or LastName, whichever is mandatory(Just A work around).